# Speed up user defined functions using arrays in excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, user-defined-functions

I created a UDF which performs a semi-complicated calculation. It uses two small one dimensional ranges (25 cells each) and two values. The UDF is used several hundreds times in some worksheets and these sheets are slughish to calculate, taking up to ~ 10 seconds for just one calculation cycle on old, slow i5 processors. Though this is not horrible, I think it should be possible to do it a lot faster, as the calculations really aren't that horribly complicated.

One of the things I'm looking at are some calculation steps in the UDF where I loop through an array, like this:

```
For i = 1 To 25
    Tr(i) = T / Tc(i)
Next i
```

or this:

```
b = 0
For i = 1 To 25
    b = b + C(i) * 0.077796 * R * Tc(i) / Pc(i)
Next i
```

Each of these loops should only take a tiny fraction of a second, so my concern for speeding it up may seem trivial. However, this type of loop exists several times in the UDF, mostlty as a one-dimensioal loop, but also some two-dimensional ones and since the UDF is called hundreds of times in my worksheet, it still adds up. I'm also working on a second UDF, which is mathematically quite a bit more complicated, using many more loops like this and am therefore worried it will be a lot slower still. Therefore I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. Can anyone suggets a faster way?

I am also wondering if I can speed up things by changing my variable definitions. I've defined each of those with what I think is the most suitable data type (integer for loop counters, double for any values, array of double for arrays of values, etc.). Is this the most efficent way for any calculations that are performed? Or would e.g. using the variant data type for everything be faster?

Comment: Please show your `DIM` statements. Variants are probably not faster but you should benchmark a few representative calculations.

Comment: Are your arrays real array or are they Ranges?

Comment: Frankly,  a UDF that loops over an array of only 25 elements,  and is called only "a few hundred times" will run very fast.   If it looped a few thousand times,  and or was called 10 of thousands of times, then sure, it`d be slow.  So, show us your whole UDF.  There are probably other reasons for it being slow

Comment: @Chris Neilsen: Yes, there are also other things that are slowing down the UDF, most notably reading of required data from a data table. I'm already working on those. That is however not the point of my question. What I want to know is if there is a more efficient way to calculate the contents of arrays. Looping through each element just seems wrong to me. It's not just about this UDF. I'm working on another that requires dozens of two dimensional arrays to be manipulated in a similar way and I want to get that right from the start.

Comment: In my experience looping arrays often performs better than alternative non looping solutions.   You'll need to assess it case by case, sometimes (occasionally) there there are faster alternatives.   Note there are many Q's here where people ask for non looping solutions,  and get answers,  which perform worse than the looping version.